# setuid create one child process

Tags: c++, c, linux

When I try to `setuid` in my program it creates 2 processes.  One is a parent process and the other is a child process .

```
int isRoot()
{
        if (getuid() != 0)
        {
                return 0;
        }
        else
        {
                return 1;
        }
}

int main()
{
    printf("%s \n \n",getUserName());
    printf("%d\n",getuid());

    if(!isRoot())
    {
        printf("This program must be run as root/sudo user!!");
        exit(0);
    }
    seteuid(1000);
    while (1) {}
    printf("%s \n \n",getUserName());
}
```

When I check with `ps` command it show me two different processes:

```
sagar@sagar-desktop:~$ ps -aef | grep a.out
root     20293 18135  0 15:36 pts/7    00:00:00 sudo ./a.out
sagar    20294 20293 99 15:36 pts/7    00:00:17 ./a.out
```

Can anyone tell me why it is creating two process instead of one ?

Comment: Your code calls `seteuid` instead of `setuid`?

Comment: I vote for leave open, because this question looks pretty clear for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's only one copy of your process here.

```
root     20293 18135  0 15:36 pts/7    00:00:00 sudo ./a.out
```

This is sudo, not your process: the ./a.out is its command line args. It then spawns your process as a child process as you've noticed:

```
sagar    20294 20293 99 15:36 pts/7    00:00:17 ./a.out
```

Answer (score 3):

You're mistaken. This is what `sudo x` does. It calls `x` as root *in a new process* and wait for it, hence the two processes.